# how to make “Creme Caramel” coffee flavored?

Tags: flavor, vietnam, dessert

[image: bonus fact: that coffee glass is "vietnamese coffee" with condensed milk super strong and sweet super recommended]

I tried it Vietnam 3 years ago. What is the name of that desert in the photo?

I only know that its origin is probably Phillipines or Vietnam or that area, and that it contains eggs, and the brown thing is coffee flavored.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, this looks like creme caramel. https://www.marthastewart.com/971530/creme-caramel

Comment: thanks for the name! i wish someone could tell me how to do the coffee trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is  either a [Flan](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flan&t=ffsb&ia=recipes), or a  [Creme Caramel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_caramel).

[The difference between flan and Creme Caramel](http://www.differencebetween.net/object/comparisons-of-food-items/difference-between-flan-and-creme-caramel/)

Flan is a custard based dessert. All though it is loved in many countries not just Asia  its origins are not Asian but ancient Rome.  there are many versions of it around the world.

[The history of flan.](https://wearecocina.com/lifestyle/the-history-of-flan/)

[The history of Creme Caramel.](https://www.world-foodhistory.com/2012/01/history-of-creme-caramel.html)

> It is known as flan in Spain and Mexico and as cream caramella in
> Italy. Flan and crème caramel, both a mixture of sugar, flavorings and
> a milk product, differ in that flan is Spanish in origin and is made
> with sweetened condensed milk while crème caramel is French in origin
> and is made with whole milk or cream.

The caramel topping may have hints of coffee flavor but technically it is not made with coffee.  It is melted sugar, melted to a slightly burnt state called caramelized sugar.

If like Flan then you will probably like [creme brulee.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e)

This is the [cooking stack exchange](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), right?

Comment: thanks man. honestly i searched for it in here:
https://stackexchange.com/sites
but couldn't find. strange

Comment: @asi It’s Seasoned Advice (Cooking SE) and would rather belong there, but we can’t migrate it as is: Recipe requests are explicitly off topic there and strictly speaking here as well.

Comment: already asked it there. thanks and i will delete this

Comment: or you guys close it whatever is possible

Comment: asi, you can’t delete a question with an accepted answer.